# Get events from Kovan Testnet

Tags: web3js, events, infura, kovan

I am trying to connect to Kovan testnet from a Node.js server. I have tried to connect in order to retrieve past events. 
Steps tried so far:- 
The connection was done via Infura. Tried these steps over multiple versions

Version 0.20.3(Version in Github):

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON);

contractAddress=<contractAddress>;
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);
var events = contractInstance.allEvents({fromBlock: 5000000, toBlock: 'latest'});

events.get(function(error, logs){
    console.log(logs);
});
```

Despite having events no output are produced. If Infura is the issue is there any other way I can get events from Kovan Testnet?

I tried web3-1.0.0.beta19 to connect to Infura via websockets but realised there are no websockets for Kovan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around by using the [zero client provider](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine). It works in a stable manner for the Mainnet and Kovan RPC connections provided by Infura.

Answer (score 0):

while starting parity with `--chain=kovan` to connect to kovan testnet use the additional options of pubsub,parity,parity_pubsub in `--ws-api`s and also add
`--jsonrpcapis=all` option.

if you start parity with the above options you will be able to register for contract events using
`contractInstance.events.MyEvents()` in your nodejs javascript code.

my nodejs application which worked perfectly while running on local ethereum node had trouble in capturing contract events while moving to kovan testnet. I was able to resolve the issue with the above options.

Copying the complete command which worked for me below.

```
parity --chain=kovan   --ws-apis="eth,net,web3,personal,web3,pubsub,parity,parity_pubsub" --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,personal" --jsonrpc-apis=all
```

Hope it helps.